# method for converting seconds from date to datetime

Tags: matlab

Is there a method in matlab to convert seconds from a known date to a standard date time format?

For example, if I have a vector of values shown as seconds from 1901/01/01, how would I convert them to a dateTime? In this case a value of 28125 would correspond to 1981/01/01. Is there an efficient method for doing this?

Comment: 28125 seconds is about 7 hours and 48 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers in your example do not make sense so it is not clear if your time is in seconds or days but since you asked for seconds I will use this.
What you want to achieve can be done using `datenum` function. This function returns the number of (fractional) days from 1/1/0000. So first you need to find your offset, e.g.:

```
offsetInDays = datenum(1901,1,1);
```

Next, you convert the date from seconds to days:

```
dateInDays = YourRequiredDateInSec * 3600 * 24;
```

Finally, you date is given by

```
RequiredDate = datestr(offsetInDays + dateInDays);
```